# How to write selenium code for validate asterisk symbol

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, testcase

How to write selenium code for validate asterisk availablity with mandatory fields e.g First Name* , Last Name* , Enter Address*, Enter Phone Number*
Need to validate asterisk availablity after the field name

Trying to write selenium code

Comment: How can an asterisk be available?

Comment: When you say "validate asterisk availability", do you mean validating that the field label contains an * if it is a required field?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
valid = driver.execute_script("""
  return arguments[0].checkValidity()
""", inputElement)
```

which will be false if the input is empty and required